# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hey guys I'm trying to create a simple program with `tkinter` and right now all I'd like it to do is open up a blank GUI.  Currently I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/firstTkinter.py", line 3, in <module>
    class simpleapp_tk(tkinter.tk):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

This is what code I've written:

```
import tkinter

class simpleapp_tk(tkinter.tk):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        tkinter.tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        'best to have a portion of code that creates all gui elements.  This is the point of initialize()'
        pass

    if __name__=='__main__':
        app=simpleapp_tk(None)
        app.title('my application')
        app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `Tk()`, not `tk()`.

Python will not recognise that name unless you give it exactly. So when you type in the latter, that object is not found and the interpreter, of course, gives you an error to let you know that the attribute that you are trying to access does not exist.

Comment: That worked.  Though now python is telling me "NameError: name 'simpleapp_Tk' is not defined".

Comment: @Matt If the only thing that you changed was from `class simpleapp_tk(tkinter.tk)` to `class simpleapp_tk(tkinter.Tk)` you should be fine. There is no need to modify the name of your class, just the object of which it is a subclass here.